# UIAlertViewDelegate not acting as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a very simple process running where after each round of a simple game the scores are calculated, labels updated and all the normal, very simple stuff. I have a UIAlertView that informs the player of how s/he performed. I use a UIAlertViewDelegate to postpone all the updates, resetting of controls etc. till after the UIAlertView is dismissed. The methods are [startNewRound],[startOver] and [updateLabels]. It's fairly obvious what they all do. Anyway, when the user hits round ten, I've made another UIAlertView that informs the player that the game has ended and shows the overall score. Again, I hoped to use a delegate to postpone the resets till after the AlertView is dismissed. The only problem is, with the endGame AlertView, it seems to be using the first AlertView's delegate method causing the game to continue with a new round and not start from the beginning. I hope this makes sense. Anyway, here are snippets of my code.

```
if (round == 10){
    UIAlertView *endGame = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle: @"End of Game"
                            message: endMessage
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"New Game"
                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [endGame show];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: title
                          message: message
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Next"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView show];
}
```

And then the delegate methods:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self startNewRound];
    [self updateLabels];
}

- (void)endGame:(UIAlertView *)endGame didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self startOver];
}
```

So there it is. As I mentioned, the endGame AlertView appears to be using alertView's delegate, thus not activating the `[self startOver]` method. All the methods are working, it's just the AlertView is using the incorrect delegate method. 
Regards,
 Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like this,

```
    if (round == 10){
        UIAlertView *endGame = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle: @"End of Game"
                                message: endMessage
                                delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"New Game"
                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        endGame.tag = 111;
        [endGame show];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: title
                              message: message
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Next"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        alertView.tag = 222;
        [alertView show];
    }
```

and delegate method as,

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        if(alertView.tag == 111)
        {
            [self startNewRound];
            [self updateLabels];
        }
        else if(alertView.tag == 222)
        {
            [self startOver];

        }
     }
```

Comment: Perfect, this combined with what Jogi said makes sense. +1 and given answer. I think my mistake was thinking that alertView delegate method was an arbitrary name and could be named anything, hence why I made one called endGame. Added the tags and worked beautifully. Thanks again.

Comment: And about the naming: alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: this is the signature of the delegate method. You can change the name of the parameter and not the actual signature of the method.

Comment: Yet again you cleared something up. I should have been able to work that out myself though! I suppose there aren't many uses to changing the name of the parameter other than readability right?

Comment: Exactly. Happy that it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You cant have two delegate method for dismisswithbuttonindex, you need to handle this situation with tag.

Give both alert view a different tag and check it on delegate object. Thus you can differentiat the both alert view.

Comment: That makes sense but I'm not entirely sure how I would implement that.